# One UIbutton can be chosen at a time

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have three buttons,and only one button can be chosen by the user at a time,that means that other then the initial state where none are chosen only one button can be at a highlighted state at a time.After another button (a forth one) is clicked,all the previous button's abilities to be clicked on are disabled.How do I do this?

Comment: first you your all button is enabled no, only one button is enable yes you have clicked like this code use [button1 setEnabled:YES];

Comment: Provide some more information about what you want to achieve and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
button.enabled = false /// this will make a button disabled in swift
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the 4th button to toggle a bool - that can be used to check on the state of the other buttons?

```
  var lockedButtons: Bool = true

  @IBAction func toggleButtonLock(sender: UIButton) {
     lockedButtons = !lockedButtons
  }

  @IBAction func Button1(sender: UIButton) {
     if !lockedButtons{
        //Button1 code
    }
  }
```

//button 2 & 3 code similar....